# Number of binary operations on a set

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

So ,in an interview I was asked to explain how to  find  the number  of  *Binary Operations* on a given set $S$  with cardinality $n.$ I was so nervous  I forgot the standard  method that as binary operations meant mappings $$S\times S \rightarrow S$$ , the number has to be $|S^{(S\times S)}|=|S|^{|S\times S|}=n^{n^2}$ in this case .

And I tried to take an alternative route that goes as follows**:**

Since ***Binary Operations*** are mappings $\tau$ $$\tau:S\times S\rightarrow S\\s.t.\ \ \ \tau:(s_1,s_2)\mapsto s_3$$ so we take a $2$-tuple and map it to another element. There are  $n^2$  ways of choosing that $2$-tuple . The first one can get mapped to any of the $n$ elements so can the second  and the $n^2$ th element . So the number is again $n^{n^2}.$

I was going right , no $?$ Or was there any fault in my way $?$ I don't know because I could not finish it there . I fumbled so badly that they showed me the way out.

Comment: Seems fine. Say, two elements $a,b$ & binary operation would take $2$ elements at a time leading to $4=\{ aa, ab, ba, bb\}$ pairs; with each mapping to $2=  \{ a, b\}$ values. So, each of four pairs mapping to two values leads to $16$ values. In fact, your expln. is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct. You want functions $S\times S \rightarrow S$. There are $|S|^{|S\times S|}$ such functions.